# MySQL how to UPDATE 1 Master Record from Many Detail Records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables -- a master and details. It's a 1-to-many relationship between master and details.

Amongst many other columns, the `master table` has:

```
id column (index)
total column
```

Amongst many other columns, the `details table` has:

```
id column (index)
value column
```

What might the SQL UPDATE statement look like to join these 2 tables together and `UPDATE master.total with the sum of details.value where master.id = details.id`

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update master as m 
set total=
(select sum(value) from detail as d where d.id=m.id)
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between this answer and MGA's?

Comment: Works perfectly @hago. Thanks! Voting this as answer due to simplicity and the fact that it worked on my first pass through.

Comment: @ypercube  Thanks MGA, his answer could be faster than mine. Mine probably executes queries on detail table many times and his using of inner join queries details table only once, especially when you have a large amount of data, mine is just plain and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Looks something like:

```
UPDATE 
master m 
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT d.id, SUM(d.value) AS valueSum
    FROM details 
    GROUP BY d.id
) AS g
  ON m.id = g.id
SET m.total = g.valueSum
```

Comment: I tried this but given the complexity of the entire syntax and my complex existing INNER JOIN ON syntax (which I know works) I am getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`. So I am going to try [at]hago's version below

Comment: it looks good and probably works. I just could not get it to work for me. Voted other answer due to fact I got it to work right away. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Dr.DOT, near what?? can you post the full error please, and you can ofcourse try hago's answer, we wish that you have a helpful answer doesn't matter whose one.

Comment: I don't have the error message any longer as I gutted the code and went with [at]hago's solution. It had less for me to tailor to my already existing SELECT statement. @MGA -- I did "up vote" you though because I am sure your answer will work as well. I just got my script running the way I need it using the other answer.

Comment: I posted my final and working query statement in the 3rd answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my final SELECT statement ended up looking like:

```
// update all scored nominations "total score" and "average score" for current year where nomination approved and not locked
mysql_query('
    UPDATE nomination_bak AS nomination
    SET
        nomination_score = (
            SELECT SUM(total_score)
            FROM essayScores_bak AS essayScores
            WHERE essayScores.nomination_sequence = nomination.nomination_sequence AND essayScores.nomination_year = nomination.nomination_year
        ),
        nomination_average = (
            SELECT AVG(total_score)
            FROM essayScores_bak AS essayScores
            WHERE essayScores.nomination_sequence = nomination.nomination_sequence AND essayScores.nomination_year = nomination.nomination_year AND essayScores.total_score > "0"
        )
    WHERE nomination.nomination_year = "' . NOMINATION_YEAR . '" AND nomination.nomination_approved = "Y" AND nomination.nomination_locked = "N"
') or die('tallyScores(nominationTable): ' . mysql_error());
```

The "_bak" part of each table just shows I tested this on a backup copy of my tables.